# MariaDB return virtualcolumn with type INT instead BIGINT

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mariadb

I have a production system that store data on a mysql v 5.6.35 instance but on my local dev environment i use MariaDB.

All was working fine until I upgraded MariaDB to the last version (10.4.6-1) on Archlinux repos.
I use Hibernate in the java code to run the following query:

```
Query query = getEntityManager()
                .createNativeQuery("select exists (select 1 from table t where t.SOME_ID = :id and t.SOME_PROPERTY = 1 and t.OTHER_PROPERTY = :property)")
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .setParameter("property", property);
return ((BigInteger) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

On production server this query return a BIGINT so it is casted in the java code as BigInteger. On my local envirnoment, MariaDB create the result virtual column with type INT so in the java code the old cast raise an exception. Because i don't want to commit such kind of casting fix into production, is there a way to tell MariaDB to return by default BIGINT when running my query?

Comment: *"I have a production system that store data on a mysql v 5.6.35 instance but on my local dev environment i use MariaDB."* Using different vendors software is asking for trouble between dev and production even if both are based on the same source code.. Even the same vendor software with a (small) minor version difference can still cause trouble troubles like wierd bugs or optimisation (runtime) difference.. **The motto use the same vendor software with the same major and minor version never ever mix**

Comment: I'm aware that the cleanest solution is to use the same version but on Archlinux the default implementation is MariaDB. If there is a chance to fix this behaviour it would be better to me instead to reainstall another dbms and export/import the data.

Comment: You could also just fix your Java code to be more flexible. There is no need to cast to `BigInteger` if you are only calling `.intValue()`. You can cast to `Number` instead.

Comment: to add to @Thilo 's comment to map MySQL's `BIGINT` you should ideally be using Java's `long`datatype if you are going to make the decision to change to code. As Java's `int` datatype is 32 bits only MySQL's `BIGINT` datatype is 64 bits..